# Problems with handling ÆØÅ (Norwegian characters) when running a sql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem that I can't understand.

Everything om my site is running smoothly, but when using Norwegian special letters the query fails to add a new row in my database. Both documents in Dreamweaver and PHPMyAdmin is set to Latin/ISO-8859-1 so it should in theory work fine. Every character displays fine when manually edit the database via PHPMyadmin. No broken letters or question marks.

My query is pretty standard.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO customers (w_id, firstname, lastname, email, company, tlf, adress, city, zipcode, country)
     VALUES ('$webshop_info[w_id]', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$company', '$tlf', '$adress', '$city', '$zipcode', '$country')");
```

Any ideas, suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere in charsets
1. php version is not suitable
2. char-set meta in html is not set
3. database collation is wrong

Try unicode instead.